# Как реализовать нормальный scroll в picturebox?

Tags: c#, winforms

Привет всем.Помогите решить проблему с picturebox.Загружаю я изображение формата dds с помощью DevIL.net dll.

```
Bitmap loadimage = DevIL.DevIL.LoadBitmap(@"C:\a\test.dds");
        pictureBox1.Image = loadimage;
```

Картинка загружается，сделал scroll picturebox +autoscroll form1= true.При передвижении scrool программа начинает жутко зависать и в конце концов вылетает ошибка связанная с System.Drawing.dll.Как можно решить проблему чтобы dds картинка нормально загружалась?
Содержимое dds изображения такое :Большое количество иконок，каждая 24х24.

Comment: «ошибка связанная с System.Drawing.dll» — какая именно ошибка?

Comment: Эту ошибку уже решил...Уже не вылетает...Щас проблема только в том что программа очень медленно работает...Нужно подождать секунд 10 после прокрутки scroll чтобы появилось изображение.

Comment: зависания связаны с тем, что при скроле происходит перерисовка избражения, и если оно большое, то все вполне логично. Можете проверить просто вызывая метод `pictureBox1.Invalidate()` в цикле с небольшим интервалом времени. Большие изображения не стоит целиком выводить в PictureBox, лучше по событию от скролабаров получать из исходного изображения нужный фрагмент и выводить только его.

Comment: А я думал наоборот(загрузка дополнительно забирает больше времени и оперативной памяти).Тогда можете подсказать как реализовать загрузка изображения по размеру.

Answer (score -1):

1. Всунь picturebox в панель.
2. На панели включаешь autoscroll.
3. У picturebox включаешь autosize.

Всё.